# How to prevent character other than number getting scanned in 'scanf("%d)'

Tags: c

whenever i put character in, itll go forever. i dont know how to prevent it so if i put in character, itll detect that its not supposed to be that.

````
printf("fisrt prime number till : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if(n >= 1)
    {
        printf("\n%d prime number till n:\n", n);
        printf("2 ");
    for(count = 2; count <= n; i++)
    {
        for(c = 2; c < i; c++)
        {
            if(i%c == 0)
                break;
        }

        if(c == i)
        {
            printf("%d ", i);
            count++;
        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error, wrong input.");
        system("pause");
    {
    ```
````

Comment: Read a whole line, with e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Then use either [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) or `sscanf` to attempt and parse the line. If you use `sscanf` then make sure to check what it [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). I recommend using `strtol` as that allows you to check that the input is *only* digits.

Comment: `if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`, if you're reading three values instead: `if (scanf("%d", &n, &o, &p) != 3) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `fgets` / `sscanf` combination.

```
        char buff[128];
        do
        {
            printf("fisrt prime number till : ");
            fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin);
        }while(sscanf(buff, "%d", &n) != 1);
```

Comment: This needs of course to be factored into a function.

Comment: And the answer needs explanations to be useful.